# JNA call to C++ function with LPCWSTR parameters

Tags: java, c++, unicode, jna

I've done a C++ dll with a function which takes unicode strings (LPCWSTR type):

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) HRESULT signFile(LPCWSTR fileName, LPCWSTR certSubject, LPCWSTR storeName);

HRESULT signFile(LPCWSTR fileName, LPCWSTR certSubject, LPCWSTR storeName)
```

A colleague of mine is trying to call this through JNA

Using String as parameter failed (the C++ function is called, but the parameters are void)

Using WString also failed.

Unfortunately, [JNA mappings](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) don't refer to LPCWSTR type.

Any idea on this?

Comment: indeed, WString wasn't properly declared by my coworker, it works now. Would you mind answering the question so as to properly close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JNI equivalent of `LPCWSTR` and `LPWSTR` is `WString`.

Java Strings map to `char*` or `LPSTR` or `LPCSTR`, but I believe will be UTF-8 endcoded, so can still pass the full character set.

Comment: Java Strings can map to either `LPCWSTR` or `LPWSTR`; if you look at how the W32 API mappings are set up, you can see how this achieved for those MS libraries which support both ANSII and UNICODE variants of function signatures.  The native layer needs an indication whether to treat Java Strings as `char*` or `wchar_t*`, and `WString` is the most basic way to do so.